# Unstyleing Anchor Tags in CSS

Tags: css

I would like all the standard styles of underline, bold and color to be removed from the anchor tag so that all an anchor tag does is link and not upset the display.

I tried the following but I still have everything inside in blue and bold which is a pain.

```
a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
}
```

Anybody know how to not just remove the style by substituting a replacement but to actually not have it style the link at all so that styles are not upset within the anchor.

Comment: And how will your users know where the links *are*, in your page? You're giving them a distinctive look, right? So people can see them?

Comment: David Thomas has a point. People can still find your links by moving the mouse over the page and see if the cursor changes. Apply `cursor:text` to the style; only then will your links be completely undetectable!

Answer (score 5):

That CSS should be working. Perhaps your stylesheet isn't being loaded? Try making the font size of links obviously large with `font-size:50px;`, for example.

If the links become large but the colour/text-decoration/font-weight still aren't inheriting then I don't know what the problem is but if the links remain the same size then your problem lies with linking your css to your html file.

Answer (score 5):

@Drejon's answer was almost what I wanted, but explicitly setting the color, text decoration and font-weight was causing `a` tags to not take those values from their parent, which is what I desired. Here is what I ended up using:

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure that I understand. Try if this helps:

```
a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
    color: #000000; /*color of your choosing*/
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest `color: inherit` if he's trying to make the `a` elements invisible, or non-distinctive.

Comment: @David Thomas, the keyword value `inherit` is not as widely supported in browsers as specific color values.

Comment: Really? What doesn't support it? But, even with edge-cases, so long as you set a browser-understandable regular colour *first* and then override with a second declaration, using `inherit`, it'll not cause any problems.